# I am writing a test case for the method "Execute" inside this its calling a private method "SimpleParseRecord" when this method is called

Tags: c#, nunit

This is the method calling "SimplePareRecord" method this "SimpleParse" method is called by a public method

```
 public void ProcessFile(IParserFile file)
    {
        if (file.SizeInBytes == 0)
        {
            file.Log.Message((int)ErrorCodes.FileIsEmpty);
            return;
        }

        switch (file.FileName.ToLower().Split('/').Last())
        {
            case "basicsysteminfo.json":
                //ParseBasicSystemInfo(file);
                SimpleParse<BasicSystemInfo, Json.BasicSystemInfo.RootObject, Json.BasicSystemInfo.Entry, Json.BasicSystemInfo.Content>(file);
                break;}}
```

below method is called by above "ProcessFile" public method

```
private void SimpleParse<T, R, E, C>(IParserFile file)
        where E : Json.Entry<C, R>
        where T : UnityBase
        where R : Json.Root<E>
    {
        try
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.Open()))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                R deserializedObj = (R)serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(R));
                SimpleParseRecord<T, R, E, C>(deserializedObj, file);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            try
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.Open()))
                {
                    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    List<R> deserializedObjs = (List<R>)serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(List<R>));
                    foreach (var obj in deserializedObjs)
                        SimpleParseRecord<T, R, E, C>(obj, file);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HandleDeserializationException(ex, file);
            }
        }
    }
```

below is the code for which is called in try block

> SimplePrseRecord

```
private void SimpleParseRecord<T, R, E, C>(R deserializedObj, IParserFile file)
        where E : Json.Entry<C, R>
        where T : UnityBase
        where R : Json.Root<E>
    {
        foreach (var item in deserializedObj.entries)
        {
            T obj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
            try
            {
                Utility.CopyShallow(item.content, obj);
                obj.ArrayId = file.Guid.ToString();
                _context.GetTable<T>().Insert(obj, file);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                file.Log.Error("Unhandled Exception", ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

below is the error

[image]

**how we can setup "entries"?**

Comment: How is `SimpleParseRecord` called? Do you have control over `deserializedObj`?

Comment: when `deserializedObj` is null, it is null. You have to change the code that calls the function so it does not provide null. However we cannot guess where that null comes from.

Comment: deserializedObj is null because we have to setup "entries" then the values will be updated. but i am unable to set it.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay SimpleParseRecord is called inside another public method.

Comment: I was meaning specifically i.e. can you share the code? The question is unanswerable without that.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay i have shared the code. actually i am new to this Nunit Testing.

Comment: You could create an `IParserFile` who's `Open()` method returns a `MemoryStream` that wraps the necessary JSON string.